# Maxima: Inconsistent result for trivial inequality

Tags: maxima

Consider the following

```
kill(all)$
assume(z>0, x>0, x<1)$
is(z + x*(1-x) > 0);
/* Above returns: true */
is(z + x-x^2 > 0);
/* Above returns: unknown */
```

As `x(1-x) = x-x^2`, and, with the assumptions above, the output should be identical?